# Spring 3 how to handle multilanguage URL with same content

Tags: java, spring, url, internationalization, translation

I want to fully internationalize my web page and have URLs translated to different languages. For example

- http://example.tld/en/page
- http://example.tld/de/pagina

all aforementioned pages should be handled by same controller and show same content (translated to desired language of course, this i know how to do - using message properties).

So my questions are:

1. How to achieve this functionality using `@RequestMapping` annotation?
2. Can I configure such aliases in properties or XML file and then "inject" them into controller? i.e.:

properties file:

```
alias.page=page:pagina
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("${alias.page}")
...
```

Or something like this.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this as well.. Have you thought of creating a custom @I18NRequestMapping("alias.page") annotation and handle it form there? would it be feasible?

Comment: or maybe provide your own custom embeddedValueResolver for RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this issue by creating own implementation of servlet [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class ExampleFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                        FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Needed for getting URL from request
        final HttpServletRequest hsRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String url = hsRequest.getRequestURI().substring(
                        hsRequest.getContextPath().length()
                     );

        /* This is just simple example. Here you can connect to database
           or read properties or XML file with your configuration */
        if ("/de/pagina".equals(url) || "/en/page".equals(url)) {
            // change url and forward 
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/page");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            // Do nothing, just send request and response to other filters
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

The controller method to handle request will then look like

```
@Controller
public class MultiLangController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String pageMethod() {        
        return ...;
    }    
}
```

Finally publish the new filter into `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyExampleFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.path.to.filter.ExampleFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyExampleFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And that should do the trick. If you don't need such flexibility, maybe [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (analogue of `.htaccess` for Java) will be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `PathVariable` in the `@RequestMapping`, with something before it so Spring can map the request:

```
@RequestMapping("myPage.do")
public String displayBasePage () {
   return("pageName"); // a hard-coded JSP
}
```

becomes

```
@RequestMapping("/someidentifier/{pageName}.do"
public String displayBasePage (
      PathVariable("pageName") String pageName) {
   return(pageName); // the language-specific JSP, or whatever else you want to do
}
```

Spring will match the `/someidentifier/` to this `RequestMapping`, and you can use whatever value you want for the `pageName`.